# Wijgrid: alert "defaultAfterCellEdit: c is null"

Tags: wijmo

After remove an element from array

```
afterCellUpdate: function(e, args) {
        d = $('#my-grid').wijgrid('data');
        for(var i in d) {
            // remove element if Zero or is not a Number
            if ((parseFloat(d[i].qty) == 0) ||
                (isNaN(parseFloat(d[i].qty)))) {
                d.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
        $('#my-grid').wijgrid('ensureControl', true);
}
```

Will result in this alert

```
defaultAfterCellEdit: c is null
```

How can I handle this message?

http://wijmo.com/topic/defaultaftercelledit-c-is-null/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are rebinding the grid in the afterCellEdit event handler while grid code calling the event is still executed. A better solution is to use ‘Delete’ button rendered in each row.

You may refer the wijmo forum link i.e. http://wijmo.com/topic/defaultaftercelledit-c-is-null/ for complete description.